# UIWebViewのサイズを変更した際に黒いボーダーが出現する。

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview

UIWebViewの幅を変更した際に黒いボーダーが右側に現れます。 
Viewの幅に比例して大きくなるようです。 
XcodeのDebug View Hierarchyで確認したところレイアウトの問題ではなさそうです。 
(UIWebView>UIScrollView>UIWebBrowserViewという部分に隙間ができていました。)

解決方法をご存知の方、教えて下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
webView.opaque = true
```

ではなく

```
webView.opaque = false
```

でうまくいかないでしょうか？
同様の現象が起こり、opaque = false, backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() の設定で黒い線の表示が消えました。

Answer (score 0):

UIWebViewに対して、以下のプロパティを設定してみてください。

```
webView.opaque = true
webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

似たような質問が本家SOにもありましたので載せておきます。ご参考までに。

- [Black line appearing at bottom of UIWebView. How to remove?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420137/black-line-appearing-at-bottom-of-uiwebview-how-to-remove)
- [Black area on UIWebView during load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732594/black-area-on-uiwebview-during-load)

Comment: その方法も試したのですが線の色が消えるだけで隙間は残ってしまいます。
ちなみにWKWebViewだとこの問題は起こりません。

Comment: `黒いボーダー`=`隙間`ということでよろしいでしょうか??
あと、今回のご質問がUIに関することとなりますので、スクリーンショットを貼っていただけると他の方も回答をしやすいかと思います。よろしくお願いします。